# Channel's uploads playlist id returning playlistNotFound

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am working on a project that gets the id of a channel's uploads playlist through their legacy username using the forUsername parameter with python3 and youtube-data-api. Here it searches for the uploads playlist string. From there, it gets the videos on their channel and the info I need.

When I try this for some channels, it works perfectly and returns exactly what I expect. With others however, it gives me a playlistNotFound error despite me printing the playlistId that I am recieving to ensure that it is correct.

The error (with playlist id UUNbg-_aV3kK4MEb2vgdBtsw from the channel ManchesterUnited):

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUNbg-_aV3kK4MEb2vgdBtsw&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSy...&alt=json returned "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.". Details: "[{'message': "The playlist identified with the request's <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.", 'domain': 'youtube.playlistItem', 'reason': 'playlistNotFound', 'location': 'playlistId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

My code:

```
from scraper_api import ScraperAPIClient
import requests
import googleapiclient.discovery
import html
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
username=input("what is the channel username? (go to page and then you will see in the url) ")
ytapi = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername="+username+"&key=AIzaSy...")
print(ytapi.text)
at=ytapi.text.split(' ')
c=1
b=0
viewnumbers = []
titles = []
vtypes = []
urls = []
for i in at:
    c+=1
    if 'uploads' in i:
        for it in at[c-3:]:
            if 'U' in it:
                print(it)
                idd=it[1:len(it)-2]
                print(idd)
                break

playlist_id = idd

youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build("youtube", "v3", developerKey = "AIzaSy...")

request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part = "snippet",
    playlistId = playlist_id,
    maxResults = 50
)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: What is your question about this observation?

Comment: What is the difference between the two channels that means that code doesn't work? And, ideally, how can I fix it?

Comment: I already have noticed this bug, it's a bug on YouTube end, you can't solve it. Just skip this YouTube channel in your study, as this channel doesn't have any videos [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) (if it was working) would return you nothing anyway.